# Grafana - Get AWS Cost usage by tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there a way to get the costs of AWS resources by tags? It is possible using Linked accounts but I'm trying to figure out if we can filter out costs by tags.

[image]

For linked accounts the query is `dimension_values(us-east-1, AWS/Billing, EstimatedCharges, LinkedAccount, {"Currency": "USD"})`

But i'm not sure what the query is for tags? This is for variable/templating.

This is how a normal graph dashboard filtering looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. CloudWatch metric `EstimatedCharges` in the `AWS/Billing` namespace doesn't provide tag dimension (only ServiceName dimension). `AWS Cost Explorer` doesn't use CloudWatch metric - there is different AWS API used, which is not implemented in the Grafana.